# Retrieving Google Authentication Token

Tags: c#, http, google-cloud-platform, httprequest, google-authentication

I figured out the correct URI to send users to a google authentication consent screen however my first problem is that when copying the URI into the browser it works fine however when my application launches the link it says "Required parameter is missing: response_type" when i have clearly set the response type to code.

My second and main problem is retrieving the token, the seemingly only way to do it is for me to set up some way of setting a dummy link as the redirect url and then using other software to read that. Is there no way to more directly send the token straight to my program or through local host or something like that?

A little note, please do not respond asking me to read googles information on this I have read it and it is useless thankyou in advance I would really appreciate the help I have been up all night stuck on this.

Comment: It sounds as you are making the request from an app (client), not from a website, is this correct? Then you need deep linking, the app has to register itself as target for a custom url scheme like "com.example.myapp". It depends on the target platform (e.g. Android) and the used framework (e.g. UWP) how you can achieve this.